# Flutter - highlight the words that is typing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When input some language that cannot input a word directly by English keyboard, like Chinese, Japanese. They use romanization to help.

For example, when input a word **你好** which is hello In English. You should input **nihao** .

And the result is that the words that is inputing is highlighted to indicate that you are typing the words currently.

Two images at the end, shows the effect. First is in native iOS, the highlight style is change the background color to light blue, 
Second is in Flutter, the style is underscore.

I want to know in flutter, how to custom the style.
Thank you ！

[native iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSEXH.jpg) [flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjgQj.png)